Verb+通り? What does it mean?
二人とも酒が入っているせいで、おぼつかない足取りだ。
そして危惧した通り、彼の足が瓶に触れた。
The character are drunk and fighting... as far I can see top line mentions their way of walking is uncertain because of the alcohol. Then he says the guy's leg hit the beer on the bottle as he does this.
But I don't understand 危惧した通り? What is 通り?

This is 通り meaning "as ～". See: JLPT N3 Grammar
とおりに (toori ni)
危惧した通り means "Just as I feared".
